# C# - Can't connect to remote MySQL server

Tags: c#, mysql

My problem is that I can't connect to my website remote MySQL server. I have read all answers in stackoverflow.com, but I can't find right answer. Here's my C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SqlConnection con;

        string connectionString = @"Server=[IP adress];Port=3306;Database=[database];Uid=[user];Pwd=[pass];"; 
        con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            Console.WriteLine ("Connection Open ! ");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Can not open connection ! ");
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); //shows what error actually occurs
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Error:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a 
connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured
to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40
Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: _"Any ideas?"_ - `Keyword not supported: 'port'.` my guess would be that the `port` keyword is not supported. Have you tried the connection string without specifying the port?

Comment: indeed: 3306 is the default port anyway, so try removing it.

Comment: I've asked for help from my hosting company, so they said that I need to use port 3306

Comment: The error message is pretty clear... Try specifying the port by adding ":[PortNumber]" at the end of your IP adress. Like this : `Server=[IP adress]:3306`

Comment: @Robis it doesn't cost you anything to try it.

Comment: I've removed port, take a look now at error

Comment: I think you need to start reading and _understanding_ error messages, once again the message is very clear : the adress of the server you indicated is not accessible. Make sure it is correct and that you can access it from your machine

Comment: @Robis you need to download `MySql Connector` and use the library in your project. then use `MySqlConnection` instead of `SqlConnection` in your code.

Comment: @imannemati Error: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Comment: @Robis Did you read my comment!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When connecting to a MySQL-Database I always used the MySQL Connector you can get here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.9.html

You have to import the MySQL namespaces to your project and then you can use the MySQLConnection instead of the SQLConnection that is, as far as I know, only for MSSQL servers.

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/423233/How-to-Connect-to-MySQL-Using-Csharp

Comment: Error: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Comment: The syntax of the MySQLConnection is possibly different to the SQLConnection.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-connection.html

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
string connectionString = @"Server=[IP adress]:3306;Database=[database];Uid=[user];Pwd=[pass];";
```

instead of

```
 string connectionString = @"Server=[IP adress];Port=3306;Database=[database];Uid=[user];Pwd=[pass];";
```